# Pseudorandom hash of two integers

Tags: random, hash, glsl, gpgpu

I need a NxN matrix with 16bit or 32bit pseudorandom uniformaly distributed numbers over the whole range of values. N is unfortunately very large (at least 1e6), so it can not be pregenerated (That would take about a TB of memory). The only viable option I can think of is using a hash of my indices i and j as matrix elements.

There are plenty of integer hash functions available, but I am not sure which ones are suitable for two reasons.

-Only 32bit unsigned integer operations available. Since N is at least 2^20 I can not naively concatenate the two indices into one 32bit key without creating unnecessary collisions.

-Pseudorandomness is important here, I am **not** building a hashtable. Most integer hashes I found are designed for hashtables and don't have very strong requirements.

A possible solution would be taking a cryptographic hash like SHA-2, but performance is important and that is just too expensive.

A suggestions on how to combine two 32bit uints into one wile avoiding collisions patterns would already help a great deal, since I could then pick from the whole range of 32bit to 32bit hashes.

Some insight on which 32bit to 32bit hashes have good randomness would also be much appreciated.

Pregenerating 1 or 2 Arrays of N random numbers is no problem if it helps.

In case it matters, the target are GPUs I am writing in recent versions of GLSL.

Comment: Without having a precise understanding of your needs, it is difficult to make a recommendation. I have had good results using [Robert Jenkins' hash function](http://www.burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/doobs.html) for similar applications over the past 20 years. It has very good avalanching properties. I'd say that's worth giving a try.

Comment: Full avalanching, uniformity and lack of patterns are my main requirements.

Comment: In that case, definitely give the Jenkins hash function a try. The author has placed the code in the public domain, so you should able to use it for just about any kind of code base. Another hash with good avalanching in my recollection is the Murmur3 hash.

Comment: Kind of obvious, but you will of course have collisions if you have 2^40 elements and only 2^32 or even just 2^16 hashes.

Answer (score 0):

What about using LCG? It is well-known fact that in the form of
xn = (a*x+c) mod 2<sup>32</sup> where `a mod 8` is 3 or 5 and `c` is odd, the resulting congruential sequence will have period 2<sup>32</sup>.

Numerical recipes: a=1664525, c=1013904223, but there are tons of them

Form unique `x` from `i, j`, and compute `xn`.

Comment: A sequence that depends on previous elememts is not suitable here.

Comment: @MaVo159 ?! You wrote `Pseudorandomness is important here`. ANY pseudorandom RNG will have dependency on previous element. Your hash function will have such dependency

Comment: No, any pseudorandom rng depends on a state, but your solution depends on the previous result, which makes it unsuitable in this context. In this case the state is the input, which is how hashes work. State is not the same as previous result in most rngs.

Comment: @MaVo159 In case of LCG, `x` is a state (and previous result as well). But in your case state/previous result would be some function of `i,j` (say, `i*N+j`), how it makes it unsuitable? `In this case the state is the input` absolutely true for LCG as well, call it like this `M[i][j] = LCG(f(i,j))`. Wrt `State is not the same as previous result in most rngs` well, this is true but I fail to see the relevance

Comment: @MaVo159 Let's consider some general RNG with following requirements. 1) state is unsigned 32bit 2) period is 2<sup>32</sup>. It means that such RNG effectively is pretty much just another name for hash function, which uniquely maps 1<->1 intput 32bit to output 32bit. So task now is to make unique state out of `i,j` so output would be different pseudorandom 32bit which could be used as matrix value at this index. LCG is simplest one to satisfy conditions 1 and 2. If you don't like LCG, you could probably look at, say, xorshift32 (+ or * varieties included), or MWC, or SWC, or ...

Comment: Supplying the state every time would be equivalent to reseeding the LCG. Most rngs don't give you output that looks random if you reseed frequently. That's why hashes algorithms exist. This is not what LCGs are designed to do and would very likely produce really bad pseudo randomness.

Comment: @MaVo159 `Supplying the state every time would be equivalent to reseeding the LCG.` yes, that's correct. `Most rngs don't give you output that looks random if you reseed frequently.` Huh?  For 32bit state -> 32bit output RNG it is definitely NOT true. `That's why hashes algorithms exist.` Huh? Hash was invented to map variable date (say, strings) to fixed index, and always tested that way. `would very likely produce really bad pseudo randomness.` don't think so, and don't believe it will introduce any additional `badness` beyond usual known LCG shortcomings

Comment: Well a simple counter is also 32bit -> 32bit, but its not very random.... Anyway, it might not be much worse given that LCGs are pretty terrible anyway. My point is: even if you replace this with a better algorithm with a more complex state, reseeding breaks the good generators.

Comment: @MaVo159 well, counter not much random, same goes for, say, simple `mod` hash function, not very random either. My pet peeve is with this statement: `reseeding breaks the good generators`. I don't believe this is true, but I would be happy to get a link where such facts are stated. Basically, you're saying that for some seeds RNG (LCG in our case)  is good and for some seeds LCG is a lot worse. I believe it is uniformly bad (or good, depends on POV) everywhere. Anyway, if hash or cipher works for you, good, further discussion is useless. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I found a suitable algorithm. Block ciphers in counter mode are obviously suitable. I initially rejected the idea because of the performance implications of most block ciphers. However, I found a paper that introduces a related algorithm (basically a block cipher with less rounds) called Philox (Parallel Random Numbers: As Easy as 1, 2, 3 by Salmon et al.).

Link: http://www.thesalmons.org/john/random123/papers/random123sc11.pdf

The only problem left is how to combine the two indices into one 32bit number. But I guess XOR should be good enough if combined with a rotation to avoid commutativity.